# Como volver focusable un label de Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estoy intentando hacer un custom control basado en un label de Xamarin Forms. La idea es que al dar click el control ejecute una accion, esto ya lo hice con GestureRecognizers.

Pero como algunos de nuestros usuarios usan un teclado, necesito que este custom control sea Focusable, y necesito detectar cuando tiene el foco para hacer cambios en sus carateristicas.

Como puedo lograr eso?

Estoy usando Xamarin Forms, y me interesa principalmente la implementacion para Android.